# Dash not showing up

Tags: unity-dash

Dash (the menu that used to appear when I pressed SUPER) is not being displayed. It does load the layout of the Dash, but I'm not able to search files(it keeps loading) nor to click in shortcuts, because they don't appear.
Compiz is taking up to 10% of my CPU but this other issue is really more important.

[image]

Could you please help me?

Comment: What happens if you try to adjust [the filters?](http://imgur.com/a/3AMzZ) Can you click in the box and provide a search term?

Comment: @ElderGeek Only web filter work, showing my Firefox bookmarks.  Some programs show up when I search for them(It wasn't working this way before, pretty strange).  But the main page is still blank.

Comment: The dash looks different because you've got it maximized. Click on maximize/minimize button in the upper-left corner of your screen, and it'll return to its normal appearance. If you click on Filters, you can tailor the results of your search.

Comment: @heynnema I never saw these little buttons. Thank you for this. I think I not being very helpful in describing my problem: the home page in the dash doesn't show anything. I can search for programs, but images and text files doesn't appear in the search.

Comment: If you type "disk" into the search arrow, and make sure that the "Application" filter is enabled (circled), you should get a number of hits. You can enable more than one filter at  time. Don't you get any hits?

Comment: @heynnema Yes, but this part is fine, the search is not the issue. The Dash page appears void, while when I installed Ubuntu, I could use it to click in the files or programs I use the most. As the ElderGeek answer showed, that button that should make something appear when the dash menu is called is broken.

Comment: Oh, I think I get it. Log into the "Guest" account and see if it operates differently there.

Comment: It shows some applications(Thunderbird, videos, gedit, 5 in total). It's not the same as was in my user before, but resembles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main dash page should be blank in the absence of a search term:

[image: blank dash]

(Unless your settings are set to record file and application usage) as shown below and you've not recently cleared your usage data:

[image: record-on]

By the same token you can turn off online results in the dash by matching this setting:

[image: web-off]

If adjusting these settings as desired doesn't provide the desired results you may need to [reset your unity configuration.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17610/how-do-i-reset-my-unity-configuration)

**Edit:** Based on your newest comments I believe that you may have recently cleared your usage data. As long as your settings are set to record file and application usage it should eventually repopulate with your recently used files and applications provided you have them selected in the filters.

To the best of my knowledge the recently used stuff that shows up in the dash is accessed from ~/.local/share/recently-used.xbel if you've inadvertently deleted this file your history is lost.

Comment: My configurations are exactly like you described. I also read the link you provided and I tried `unity --reset` and I also reinstalled unity(I don`t really know what it is yet). But nothing changed. Thanks for you help and sorry my english.

Comment: To the best of my knowledge the recently used stuff that shows up in the dash is accessed from ~/.local/share/recently-used.xbel  see my edited answer

Answer (score 0):

I just had this issue earlier today.

What I did was uninstalling and installing back the unity-lens application:

```
sudo apt purge unity-lens-applications
sudo apt install unity-lens-applications
```

Let me know if it worked for you.
Oh! You must restart your computer for it to take effect.